# How to align first item at the start and second item of a row at the end?

Tags: flutter-layout

I am not able to separate two items with space so that first item appears at the start of row and second at the end of it.

```
                  Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Row(
                           crossAxisAlignment: 
                                CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          mainAxisAlignment: 
                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                                child: Text("Select your service",
                                    style: profileValueTextStyle),
                                onTap: () {

                                  print("-----" + result);
                                }),
                            Icon(Icons.close)
                          ],
                        ),),
```

I want to separate the text and close icon.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your `InkWell` into a `Expanded Widget`:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
  child: Row(
     crossAxisAlignment: 
          CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisAlignment: 
      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(                                        //Here's the widget you need
        InkWell(
            child: Text("Select your service",
                style: profileValueTextStyle),
            onTap: () {

              print("-----" + result);
            }),
        ),
      Icon(Icons.close)
    ],
  ),),
```

It's gonna "push" the `Icon` to the end of the row.

Hope it's helps !!

Comment: i have tried this, whole view gets invisible. i have also tried Split() but it also didnt work.

Comment: I was making a mistake in parent of Container. I worked now. thanks for the answer.